# Solar System Grounding

Tags: inverter, grounding, solar-energy

- Solar panels and structure should be grounded to DC or AC?
- Inverter chassis/body should be grounded to AC or DC?

Comment: Did you read the installation manual for your inverter?  All of these questions and more should be covered there.

Comment: Grounds should be connected... to Earth grounds.  The whole point of grounding is to tie the exterior touchable surfaces to the Earth; so that a human (standing on the Earth), touching the surfaces, does not get shocked.  As jwh20 says, the install manuals dictate the details of how this must be done for safety and compliance.